# Improve contour plot from xyz coordinates in Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scatter-plot, contour

I'm trying to do a scatter plot with xyz coordinates (dataset [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14EURMJMnNLrZmehPjV0E2In_RGJI0DXX/view?usp=sharing)) overlaid on a contour plot (i.e., elevation map - dataset [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uZ98pRy3uGcJf3dDcy9gG5xWl0UjOr7V/view?usp=sharing)).
I'm able to create the contour and scatter but I was wondering if it's possible to increase the resolution of the elevation map so that the elevation has more different colours?
Also, I'd like the scatter plot to have a different color scheme than the contours so that there are 2 different colormaps with legend next to the plot. One for 'z' and one for 'var'

Here is the code that I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

csv = 'Sand.csv'
csv2 = 'xyzData.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(csv, header=None, names=['sample', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'mean', 'sort', 'skew', 'kurt'])
df2 = pd.read_csv(csv2, header=None, names=['x', 'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3'])

x = df2['x']
y = df2['y']
z = df2 ['z']

x1 = df['x']
y1 = df['y']
z1 = df['z']
var = df['sort']

a1 = df['x'].max()
b1 = df['x'].min()
c1 = df['y'].max()
d1 = df['y'].min()

def plot_contour(x,y,z,resolution = 1000,contour_method='linear'):
    resolution = str(resolution)+'j'
    X,Y = np.mgrid[min(x):max(x):complex(resolution),   min(y):max(y):complex(resolution)]
    points = [[a,b] for a,b in zip(x,y)]
    Z = griddata(points, z, (X, Y), method=contour_method)
    return X,Y,Z

X,Y,Z = plot_contour(x,y,z,resolution = 1000,contour_method='linear')

with plt.style.context("seaborn-dark"):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(13,8))
    ax.scatter(x,y, color="black", linewidth=1, edgecolor="ivory", s=100)
    ax.contourf(X,Y,Z)
    ax.scatter(x1, y1, z1, c=var)
    ax.set_xlim(b1, a1)
    ax.set_ylim(d1, c1)
        
plt.show()
```

This is what I get now
[image]

But I'd like the something like the following 2 in 1 picture:
[image][image]

Comment: You could try more levels in `ax.contourf(X,Y,Z, levels=30)` and a colormap (the example uses `cmap='jet'` which often can be dangerous because of its yellow highlight).  You can also try `method='cubic'` which would create nicer looking curves (but not necessarily "more correct").

Comment: Thank you! That's all working. Can I increase the size of the marker of the scatter data independently? Now it says I have multiple values for "s", but would like the markers bigger of the scatter...

Comment: With `ax.scatter(x1, y1, z1, c=var)`  you are using `s=z1`.  Note that your scatter plot is 2D and that `s` is an indication of the area, not the diameter.  If your `z1` should be considered a diameter you could try `s=z1**2` or `s=10+z1**2`, or even just `s=50` and leaving out `z1`.